# Selecting elements in an array based on what column and row they are in in order to complete a loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Say I had the following:

```
x = np.array([[1.,2.,3.,4.],[2.,3.,4.,5,],[1.,3.,5.,6.]])
```

What would the syntax be in order to select say, the first two columns of every row? (So `[[1.,2.],[2.,3.],[1.,3.]]`).

Ultimately I want to run a loop of the form:

```
for j in range(len(x)):
     a = x[1,2:j] * #something
```

Where `x[1,2:j]` refers to what I am trying to achieve in my question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.hsplit()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html#numpy.hsplit) (Split an array into multiple sub-arrays horizontally (column-wise).) then chose the fist part :

```
>>> np.hsplit(x,2)[0]
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  3.]])
```

Or you can just use [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) :

```
>>> x[:, :2]
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  3.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice axis 1 of the array `x`:

```
>>> x[:, :2]
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  3.]])
```

The `:` for axis 0 effectively means "every row". The `:2` in axis 1 means "get the first two columns (0 and 1)".

Slicing in multiple dimensions works similarly to Python lists and other iterables,

```
start:stop:step
```

You can specify a slice for each dimension of the array, or use `:` to get everything along the axis.